# for loop в Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, for

Еще не успел освоить что то более сложное чем простые циклы в `kotlin`, поэтому не знаю как можно взять индекс в самом теле цикла.
Для примера на `java` цикл выглядит так:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++)
```

В `kotlin` пробую такую конструкцию:

```
for (i in 2..n.div(i))
```

где вторая `i` выделана как не разпознаная. Как вызвать индекс в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Цикл `for` в Kotlin не занимается микроменеджментом переменной-счётчика, он перебирает элементы `Iterable`. В вашем примере `2..n` - это объект типа `IntRange`, перебор элементов которого даёт целые числа от 2 до `n`, которые и присваиваются переменной `i` на каждой итерации цикла. Перебираемый объект создаётся до вхождения в цикл, изменять его во время перебора нельзя. Аналогом из Java для такого цикла будет цикл `foreach`: `for (Integer i : ints)`. Если вам нужно в Kotlin менять условие выхода из цикла на каждой итерации, воспользуйтесь циклом `while`.

Comment: стоит сказать что реализация с while работает но сильно уродует код.

Answer (score 4):

Можно решить эту проблему проще

Java:

```
int cond = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
for (int i = 2; i <= cond; i++)
     System.out.println(i);
```

Kotlin:

```
val cond: Int = sqrt(n.toDouble()).toInt()
for (i in 2..cond) println(i)
```

[О том как работает Ranges в Kotlin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1007787/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-ranges-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B2-kotlin/1007788#1007788)

Comment: Это работает, но не могли бы вы подробнее обьяснить как в данном случае работает range?

Comment: @UjinUkr добавил

Comment: Как `val cond` зависит от значения итератора цикла? Об этом же автор спрашивал.