# Как работает Ranges (оператор ..) в Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Каким образом работает оператор `..` в Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `..`, это метод `rangeTo`

```
public operator fun <T : Comparable<T>> T.rangeTo(that: T): ClosedRange<T> = ComparableRange(this, that)
```

Класс `ComparableRange` представляет собой класс диапазонов которые сравниваются между собой.

```
/**
 * Represents a range of [Comparable] values.
 */
private open class ComparableRange<T : Comparable<T>>(
    override val start: T,
    override val endInclusive: T
) : ClosedRange<T> {

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return other is ComparableRange<*> && (isEmpty() && other.isEmpty() ||
                start == other.start && endInclusive == other.endInclusive)
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return if (isEmpty()) -1 else 31 * start.hashCode() + endInclusive.hashCode()
    }

    override fun toString(): String = "$start..$endInclusive"
}
```

Он наследует интерфейс `ClosedRange`, который предоставляет метод сравнения `lessThanOrEquals`.

```
public interface ClosedRange<T: Comparable<T>> {
    /**
     * The minimum value in the range.
     */
    public val start: T

    /**
     * The maximum value in the range (inclusive).
     */
    public val endInclusive: T

    /**
     * Checks whether the specified [value] belongs to the range.
     */
    public operator fun contains(value: T): Boolean = value >= start && value <= endInclusive

    /**
     * Checks whether the range is empty.
     */
    public fun isEmpty(): Boolean = start > endInclusive
}
```

Когда вы создаёте range целых чисел (`1..10` \ `1.rangeTo(10)`), создаётся `IntRange`

```
/**
 * A range of values of type `Int`.
 */
public class IntRange(start: Int, endInclusive: Int) : IntProgression(start, endInclusive, 1), ClosedRange<Int> {
    override val start: Int get() = first
    override val endInclusive: Int get() = last

    override fun contains(value: Int): Boolean = first <= value && value <= last

    override fun isEmpty(): Boolean = first > last

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
            other is IntRange && (isEmpty() && other.isEmpty() ||
                    first == other.first && last == other.last)

    override fun hashCode(): Int =
            if (isEmpty()) -1 else (31 * first + last)

    override fun toString(): String = "$first..$last"

    companion object {
        /** An empty range of values of type Int. */
        public val EMPTY: IntRange = IntRange(1, 0)
    }
}
```

Который в свою очередь унаследован от `IntProgression`.

```
public open class IntProgression
internal constructor
(
        start: Int,
        endInclusive: Int,
        step: Int
) : Iterable<Int> {
    init {
        if (step == 0) throw kotlin.IllegalArgumentException("Step must be non-zero.")
        if (step == Int.MIN_VALUE) throw kotlin.IllegalArgumentException("Step must be greater than Int.MIN_VALUE to avoid overflow on negation.")
    }

    /**
     * The first element in the progression.
     */
    public val first: Int = start

    /**
     * The last element in the progression.
     */
    public val last: Int = getProgressionLastElement(start.toInt(), endInclusive.toInt(), step).toInt()

    /**
     * The step of the progression.
     */
    public val step: Int = step

    override fun iterator(): IntIterator = IntProgressionIterator(first, last, step)

    /** Checks if the progression is empty. */
    public open fun isEmpty(): Boolean = if (step > 0) first > last else first < last

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean =
            other is IntProgression && (isEmpty() && other.isEmpty() ||
                    first == other.first && last == other.last && step == other.step)

    override fun hashCode(): Int =
            if (isEmpty()) -1 else (31 * (31 * first + last) + step)

    override fun toString(): String = if (step > 0) "$first..$last step $step" else "$first downTo $last step ${-step}"

    companion object {
        /**
         * Creates IntProgression within the specified bounds of a closed range.

         * The progression starts with the [rangeStart] value and goes toward the [rangeEnd] value not excluding it, with the specified [step].
         * In order to go backwards the [step] must be negative.
         *
         * [step] must be greater than `Int.MIN_VALUE` and not equal to zero.
         */
        public fun fromClosedRange(rangeStart: Int, rangeEnd: Int, step: Int): IntProgression = IntProgression(rangeStart, rangeEnd, step)
    }
}
```

В данном классе и присутствует метод `iterator()`, который возвращает объект `IntProgressionIterator`.

```
/**
 * An iterator over a progression of values of type `Int`.
 * @property step the number by which the value is incremented on each step.
 */
internal class IntProgressionIterator(first: Int, last: Int, val step: Int) : IntIterator() {
    private val finalElement = last
    private var hasNext: Boolean = if (step > 0) first <= last else first >= last
    private var next = if (hasNext) first else finalElement

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = hasNext

    override fun nextInt(): Int {
        val value = next
        if (value == finalElement) {
            if (!hasNext) throw kotlin.NoSuchElementException()
            hasNext = false
        }
        else {
            next += step
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

А дальше уже знакомый паттерн `Iterator`, который просто перебирает все элементы от первого до конца, но в случае с числами просто добавляется шаг (`step`).

Реализация:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/ranges/Ranges.kt
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/ranges/Ranges.kt
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/ranges/Progressions.kt
https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/runtime/src/main/kotlin/kotlin/ranges/ProgressionIterators.kt